# Cannot upload data to Cosm from arduino mega by tutorial sketch

Tags: c, upload, arduino, cosm, xively

I cannot upload data from my Arduino Mega with Ethernet Shiled to Cosm. I tried one of the tutorial examples ([`DatastreamUpload.ino`](https://github.com/cosm/cosm-arduino/blob/master/examples/DatastreamUpload/DatastreamUpload.ino)). I used the API key and feed ID that Cosm gave to me at the registration and changed the `init()` function to use a static IP address as below:

```
    byte mac[] = {0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0D, 0xD3, 0x45 };
    IPAddress ip(192,168,0, 110);
    IPAddress gateway(192,168,0, 1);
    IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
```

then:

```
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);
```

Here is the output from serial monitor:

```
Read sensor value 452.00
Uploading it to Cosm
cosmclient.put returned -1

Read sensor value 451.00
Uploading it to Cosm
cosmclient.put returned -1

Read sensor value 378.00
Uploading it to Cosm
cosmclient.put returned -3

Read sensor value 352.00
Uploading it to Cosm
cosmclient.put returned -3
```

Does someone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lack of documentation on this at the moment, one needs to look at the source code to find out. These error codes are defined in [`HttpClient.h`](https://github.com/amcewen/HttpClient/blob/master/HttpClient.h) as below:

```
// The end of the headers has been reached.  This consumes the '\n'
static const int HTTP_SUCCESS =0;
// Could not connect to the server
static const int HTTP_ERROR_CONNECTION_FAILED =-1;
// This call was made when the HttpClient class wasn't expecting it
// to be called.  Usually indicates your code is using the class
// incorrectly
static const int HTTP_ERROR_API =-2;
// Spent too long waiting for a reply
static const int HTTP_ERROR_TIMED_OUT =-3;
// The response from the server is invalid, is it definitely an HTTP
// server?
static const int HTTP_ERROR_INVALID_RESPONSE =-4;
```

Comment: i saw yet the cosm forum and i understand that arduino can't communicate with pachube server. But i don'it understand why.
If i try to start ethernet with DHCP like this:
        Ethernet.begin(mac)
sometimes data arrive to pachube... 
This is still a mistery to me! Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: Using DHCP would probably be a good start on debugging this... It's very likely to be an issue with IP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Unsurprisingly, the ino you link to looks 100% kosher and I struggle to see anything different from what I have used.

As a precaution I would put
int ret=0;
at the start of the loop

I realise you have only one sensor but suggest you meticulously identify it as sensorId0

I have a buffer

`const int bufferSize = 100;
char bufferValue[bufferSize]; 
CosmDatastream datastreams[] = {
CosmDatastream(sensorId0, strlen(sensorId0), DATASTREAM_FLOAT),`

The full bottle was published on the cosm forum last October.

I don't use that ip, gateway and subnet stuff. It is probably muddying the water.